# Problem while displaying live web camera video using flask and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, flask, computer-vision

I have been doing a project where flask and OpenCV are combined. What I am trying to do is, when the button is pressed, OpenCV should read realtime video from a web camera and display it. And It does too but only for the first time, when  ever the button is pressed second time, it keeps loading the program halts.

I have attached the program code so that one can understand the question well. 
This is the content from main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import cv2
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'sdjflajsdhfj23h4jkhwkjhasdjkhdkjfhsfd' 

@app.route('/')
def get_homepage():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/add-sample', methods = ['POST'])
def add_sample():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        if not cam.isOpened():
            return redirect(url_for('get_homepage'))

        while (cam.isOpened()):
            con, frame = cam.read()

            if con:
                cv2.imshow('test', frame)

                if cv2.waitKey(25) == 27:
                    break
            else:
                break
        cam.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()    

        return redirect(url_for('get_homepage'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The content for the template file associated with the project is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Streaming </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Streaming </h1>
    <form action="{{url_for('add_sample')}}" method="POST">
      <input type="submit" value="add sample">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem might be on releasing on the captured frames but I have tried that too but It didn't help me.

Comment: I'm not an expert in cv2, but did you tried putting the release() and destroyAllWindows() in `if` condition before break?